# Extract python file name from a class type object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below directory structure in my python project.

```
checks/
  __init__.py
  check_1.py
  check_2.py
main.py
```

Contents inside init.py file are as below where Check1 and Check2 are classes inside check_1.py and check_2.py respectively -

```
__init__.py - 

from .check_1 import Check1
from .check_2 import Check2
```

Inside main.py, i am creating the below dictionary -

```
import checks
check_dict={obj:name for name, obj in vars(checks).items() if isinstance(obj, type)}
```

Current Output -

```
{<class 'checks.check_1.Check1'>: 'Check1', <class 'checks.check_2.Check2'>: 'Check2'}
```

Expect Output -

```
{check_1: 'Check1',check_2: 'Check2'}
```

Comment: You have asked essentially the same question 4 times now. Perhaps you might step back and think if there is a more fundamental question you need answered

Answer (score 1):

`__module__` will get you the name of the module, eg. `checks.check_1`. If you only need `check_1` you can split the string:

```
check_dict={obj.__module__.split('.')[1]:name for name, obj in vars(checks).items() if isinstance(obj, type)}
```

Comment: The problem is that check1 is coming as a string value but in reality it is a class name of type BaseCheck